# How can I obtain a reference to the native window of the camera application in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, nativewindow

I need a reference to a ANativeWindow structure to be fed to a image processing library based on OpenGL. I don't want to make a native activity or an additional application.
 I also want to know if I can use, and how to obtain from native code, the window specific to the camera application, mentioning that I don't want the display to change during processing or the processing of the OpenGL based library to interfere with the camera application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I obtain a reference to the native window of the camera application in Android?

You don't. That window is in another process, not yours.

> I also want to know if I can use, and how to obtain from native code, the window specific to the camera application

This is not possible. Again, that window is in another process, not yours.

Comment: Ok, in this case, is there any way to create a native window, lacking an application?

Comment: @ionela.voinescu: Without an application, you have no code of yours to run to do anything, let alone create a native window.

Comment: My code is in the image processing library and in the changes brought to the camera HAL. So it's based on the camera application, but, as you said I can't have access to the window of the camera application. 
What I've tried until now was using android_createDisplaySurface but that required me to stop the Android run time engine during my test, so that's not a permanent solution. 
My target functionality involves using the OpenGL based library to process the frames from the camera before being displayed. So creating some additional application would not help.

Comment: @ionela.voinescu: "My target functionality involves using the OpenGL based library to process the frames from the camera before being displayed" -- that would require changes to the Android source code, compiled into custom device firmware or a ROM mod. After all, there are thousands of apps that use the camera, and the only way you can affect them all is to modify Android itself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @ionela.voinescu: I would suggest that you open up a fresh StackOverflow question, one where instead of assuming a solution ("How can I obtain a reference to the native window of the camera application in Android?"), you explain what you are trying to do ("using the OpenGL based library to process the frames from the camera before being displayed"). There are *very* few people in this world who might be able to answer that, but they are more likely to find your question if the question is focused on your real problem.